# Double integral and vanishing of integrand

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, functions

Consider a double integral $$\int_{n}^{\infty} 
   \int_{0}^{1}f(x,t) \ dx dt    $$

Then can $f(x,y)=0$ for some $x,t$ such that $x=g(t)$?

I will try to explain my question with an example:

Consider $$\int_{n}^{\infty} 
   \int_{0}^{1}((t x^{t-1}-(t+1)x^t)\left(\frac{1}{(t+1)(t+2)}\right) \ dx dt    $$

So if integrand in this example is $0$, then $$t x^{t-1}-(t+1)x^t=0$$ which gives $x=\frac{t}{t+1}$. Is this possible? Can $x$ depend on $t$ in a double integral with constant limits of integration?

Comment: The question is very obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't. Actually, you are mixing up two different things. Indeed, an area integral such as $\int\mathrm{d}x\int\mathrm{d}y\ f(x,y)$ needs two independent variables $-$ here : $x$ and $y$, obviously $-$, which parametrize the said (two-dimensional) area, while they would be functions of one another, for instance as a result of a constraint equation such as $f(x,y) = 0$, in the case where $x(y)$ $-$ or equivalently $y(x)$ $-$ represents a curve in the plane, that is a one-dimensional (i.e. one-parameter) object inside a two-dimensional space.

In conclusion, we talk about two different situations, without any link between them, even if $f(x,y)$, as a bivariate map, can serve two roles, namely as an integrand or as a curve "definition" in a 2D space.